# OpenCV Error: Camera Calibration: Assertion failed in matrix_wrap.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, assertion

The Error:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (i < 0) in cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray::getMat_, 
file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 50
```

The Code inside "matrix_wrap.cpp" that triggers the Error:

```
if( k == STD_VECTOR )
{
    CV_Assert( i < 0 );
    int t = CV_MAT_TYPE(flags);
    const std::vector<uchar>& v = *(const std::vector<uchar>*)obj;

    return !v.empty() ? Mat(size(), t, (void*)&v[0]) : Mat();
}
```

Entire Code:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>  


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

cv::Size imageSize = cv::Size(img.size[0], img.size[1]);

cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;

double squareSize = 30;

cv::Size boardSize = cv::Size(6, 11);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> imagePoints;
std::vector<cv::Point3f> objectPoints;

for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++) {
        objectPoints.push_back(
            cv::Point3f(float(j * squareSize), float(i * squareSize), 0));
    }
}

std::vector<cv::Mat>  rvecs, tvecs;

bool found = false;

if (img.size[0] > 1)
{

    bool found = findChessboardCorners(img, boardSize, imagePoints, cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH);

    if (found)
    {
        drawChessboardCorners(img, boardSize, imagePoints, found);
    }

    objectPoints.resize(imagePoints.size(), objectPoints[0]);

    double rms = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    cv::imshow("My Image", img);
    cv::waitKey(1000);

}
return 0;
}
```

I want to use a basic camera calibration with a straigth chessboard.
Until the function "calibrateCamera" everything works fine, but I can't figure out why this Error shows up.

The size of "objectPoints" and "imagePoints" is the same.
Thank you in advance.

P.S.:
I'm new in this forum and also in OpenCV ;)

Comment: Hard to tell anything without seeing the rest of the code. Please include the entire code of the function where the assert fails.

Comment: All right, I edited the code.

Comment: My guess is you use the wrong type for objectPoints. I came across this while reading the source of opencv : CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f"); (See line 3139 of https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0f298a42032798d2d83017030621fcba885a3372/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp)

Comment: Great that was the Error, also "imagePoints" should contaion vector of vectors. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I'll convert the comment to an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this source of opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0f298a42032798d2d83017030621fcba885a3372/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp), lines 3139 and 3142 :

```
CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f");
CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "imagePoints1 should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point2f");
```

the types for `objectPoints` and `imagePoints` should be `std::vector<std::vector<Point{2|3}f>>`